# R programming with tidyverse: arguments passed to glue

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working on a few functions in which the body contains `magrittr` pipes.
I am struggling with calling the arguments passed to the function inside the pipe.
The pipe works outside the function.

Here is my repex.

Just in case, I pasted the whole filtered data that I am working on:

```
timeseries <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 
18635, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 18646, 18647, 18648, 
18649, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 
18662, 18663, 18666, 18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18674, 18675, 
18676, 18677, 18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18687, 18688, 
18689, 18690, 18691, 18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18701, 
18702, 18703, 18704, 18705, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 
18715, 18716, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18638, 18639, 
18640, 18641, 18642, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18652, 18653, 
18654, 18655, 18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18666, 
18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18674, 18675, 18676, 18677, 18680, 
18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18687, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 
18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18701, 18702, 18703, 18704, 
18705, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 18715, 18716, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 
18645, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 
18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18666, 18667, 18668, 
18669, 18674, 18675, 18676, 18677, 18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 
18684, 18687, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 18694, 18695, 18696, 
18697, 18698, 18701, 18702, 18703, 18704, 18705, 18708, 18709, 
18710, 18711, 18712, 18715, 18716, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 
18635, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 18646, 18647, 18648, 
18649, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 
18662, 18663, 18666, 18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18674, 18675, 
18676, 18677, 18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18687, 18688, 
18689, 18690, 18691, 18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18701, 
18702, 18703, 18704, 18705, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 
18715, 18716, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18638, 18639, 
18640, 18641, 18642, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18652, 18653, 
18654, 18655, 18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18666, 
18667, 18668, 18669, 18670, 18674, 18675, 18676, 18677, 18680, 
18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18687, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 
18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18701, 18702, 18703, 18704, 
18705, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 18715, 18716, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 
18645, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 
18656, 18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18675, 18676, 18677, 
18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18688, 18689, 18690, 18691, 
18694, 18695, 18696, 18697, 18698, 18701, 18702, 18703, 18704, 
18705, 18708, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 18715, 18716), class = "Date"), 
    Key = c("AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", 
    "HPQ", "HPQ", "HPQ", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "0992.HK", 
    "0992.HK", "0992.HK", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", 
    "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "DELL", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", 
    "ACER", "ACER", "ACER", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW", 
    "2357.TW", "2357.TW", "2357.TW"), Open = c(133.520004, 128.889999, 
    127.720001, 128.360001, 132.429993, 129.190002, 128.5, 128.759995, 
    130.800003, 128.779999, 127.779999, 128.660004, 133.800003, 
    136.279999, 143.070007, 143.600006, 143.429993, 139.520004, 
    135.830002, 133.75, 135.729996, 135.759995, 136.300003, 137.350006, 
    136.029999, 136.619995, 136.479996, 135.899994, 134.350006, 
    135.490005, 131.25, 129.199997, 130.240005, 128.009995, 123.760002, 
    124.940002, 124.68, 122.589996, 123.75, 128.410004, 124.809998, 
    121.75, 120.980003, 120.93, 119.029999, 121.690002, 122.540001, 
    120.400002, 121.410004, 125.699997, 124.050003, 122.879997, 
    119.900002, 120.330002, 123.330002, 122.82, 119.540001, 120.349998, 
    121.650002, 120.110001, 24.700001, 24.08, 24.620001, 25.27, 
    25.690001, 25.5, 25.83, 25.99, 25.58, 25.459999, 25.26, 25.219999, 
    25.41, 25.110001, 25.219999, 25.190001, 24.18, 24.98, 24.77, 
    24.48, 24.780001, 24.860001, 25.209999, 26, 26.370001, 27.33, 
    27.209999, 27.299999, 27.379999, 27.530001, 27, 26.09, 26.700001, 
    26.99, 27.030001, 27.299999, 27.9, 29.42, 29.370001, 29.42, 
    29.940001, 29.459999, 28.299999, 29.610001, 30.040001, 30.059999, 
    30.370001, 30.26, 30.26, 30.809999, 30.290001, 30.559999, 
    30.040001, 30.110001, 30.34, 29.73, 29.110001, 30.02, 31.59, 
    31, 7.18, 7.48, 7.5, 7.46, 7.56, 7.78, 7.51, 9.25, 8.75, 
    8.65, 8.63, 9.25, 9.18, 9.14, 9.13, 9.35, 9.6, 9.9, 9.62, 
    9.32, 9.04, 9.86, 9.74, 9.83, 9.6, 9.86, 9.7, 10.06, 10, 
    10.22, 10.28, 10.7, 10.6, 10.72, 9.99, 10.3, 10.3, 9.94, 
    10.04, 10.5, 10.3, 10.2, 9.77, 10.08, 9.79, 9.85, 9.86, 10.32, 
    9.8, 9.15, 9.08, 9, 9.17, 9.27, 9.57, 9.61, 9.72, 9.74, 9.99, 
    10.04, 37.450584, 36.441967, 37.161682, 38.01318, 38.824127, 
    38.656868, 38.449062, 37.886467, 36.137859, 37.07552, 37.795235, 
    38.489609, 39.310696, 38.423721, 38.692348, 38.52002, 37.81551, 
    37.42524, 37.222504, 37.328941, 39.016727, 38.90015, 39.619869, 
    40.293968, 40.54739, 40.1926, 40.461227, 40.466293, 40.314243, 
    40.937656, 39.959454, 39.898632, 40.881905, 40.886974, 40.54739, 
    40.947796, 41.054234, 40.892044, 41.09478, 42.067917, 42.108463, 
    42.280792, 42.508869, 43.547897, 43.63406, 44.059807, 44.602131, 
    44.865688, 44.977192, 45.362392, 44.997467, 45.848961, 44.460213, 
    44.313229, 44.135834, 43.755703, 43.162697, 43.928028, 44.941711, 
    44.439938, 2.64, 2.54, 2.57, 2.5, 2.51, 2.48, 2.49, 2.63, 
    2.85, 3.01, 3.76, 4.23, 3.93, 3.59, 4.78, 4.43, 3.78, 3.64, 
    3.85, 3.71, 3.64, 3.7, 3.96, 4.06, 4.05, 4.01, 4, 4.15, 4, 
    3.88, 3.77, 3.74, 3.53, 3.55, 3.21, 3.19, 3.3, 3.21, 3.23, 
    3.5, 3.29, 3.24, 2.83, 2.87, 2.87, 3.12, 3.2, 3.17, 5.3, 
    3.84, 3.52, 3.55, 3.38, 4.14, 3.79, 3.63, 3.12, 3.16, 3.07, 
    2.98, 250.5, 251, 254, 255, 265, 282.5, 285, 285, 289.5, 
    289, 286, 283, 284, 278, 282, 284.5, 291, 287, 288, 289.5, 
    285, 285, 288.5, 288.5, 289.5, 294, 289.5, 289.5, 291.5, 
    290, 291, 308.5, 300.5, 310, 311, 315, 309, 312, 318.5, 316, 
    315, 319, 322.5, 329.5, 331, 358, 368, 382, 373, 366.5, 367, 
    366.5, 366.5, 377), High = c(133.610001, 131.740005, 131.050003, 
    131.630005, 132.630005, 130.169998, 129.690002, 131.449997, 
    131, 130.220001, 128.710007, 132.490005, 139.669998, 139.850006, 
    145.089996, 144.300003, 144.300003, 141.990005, 136.740005, 
    135.380005, 136.309998, 135.770004, 137.399994, 137.419998, 
    136.960007, 137.880005, 136.990005, 136.389999, 135.529999, 
    136.009995, 132.220001, 130, 130.710007, 129.720001, 126.709999, 
    125.559998, 126.459999, 124.849998, 127.93, 128.720001, 125.709999, 
    123.599998, 121.940002, 121, 122.059998, 122.169998, 123.209999, 
    121.169998, 124, 127.220001, 125.860001, 123.18, 121.43, 
    123.870003, 124.239998, 122.900002, 121.660004, 121.480003, 
    122.580002, 120.400002, 24.940001, 24.719999, 25.379999, 
    25.799999, 25.940001, 25.93, 26.15, 26.040001, 25.93, 25.57, 
    25.379999, 25.32, 25.440001, 25.35, 25.27, 25.360001, 25.24, 
    25.35, 24.99, 24.58, 25, 25.34, 25.959999, 26.58, 27.360001, 
    27.549999, 27.530001, 27.48, 27.5, 27.68, 27.08, 26.450001, 
    27.139999, 27.35, 27.440001, 28.26, 30, 30.25, 30.440001, 
    30.290001, 30.280001, 29.85, 29.780001, 30.68, 30.559999, 
    30.57, 30.48, 30.83, 30.809999, 30.98, 30.790001, 31.110001, 
    30.32, 30.719999, 30.57, 30.26, 30.02, 31.690001, 31.940001, 
    31.66, 7.68, 7.68, 7.67, 7.73, 7.95, 8.04, 8.12, 9.42, 9.09, 
    8.94, 9.4, 9.49, 9.27, 9.56, 9.52, 9.87, 10.08, 10.04, 9.94, 
    9.5, 9.79, 10.16, 10.5, 10, 10.04, 10.08, 10.18, 10.42, 10, 
    10.4, 10.76, 11.12, 10.72, 10.72, 10.48, 10.34, 10.46, 10.1, 
    10.4, 10.8, 10.54, 10.4, 10.06, 10.1, 10, 10.12, 10.5, 10.4, 
    9.94, 9.26, 9.15, 9.31, 9.32, 9.56, 9.78, 9.83, 9.72, 10.16, 
    10.16, 11.36, 37.450584, 37.496201, 38.129753, 38.697414, 
    39.234669, 38.945766, 38.90522, 38.00304, 37.430309, 37.962494, 
    38.028381, 39.118095, 39.391788, 38.611252, 38.71262, 38.768372, 
    38.388241, 38.109478, 37.800304, 37.871262, 39.396858, 39.700962, 
    40.212875, 40.587936, 40.907249, 40.511909, 40.54739, 40.608212, 
    40.577801, 41.008617, 40.532185, 40.816017, 41.216423, 41.550938, 
    40.993412, 41.520527, 41.358337, 42.164219, 42.290928, 42.356815, 
    42.660923, 42.777496, 43.431324, 43.938164, 44.53117, 44.657883, 
    45.347187, 45.027878, 45.27116, 45.509377, 46.381145, 45.848961, 
    44.987328, 44.744045, 44.576786, 44.298023, 44.044601, 45.108971, 
    45.428284, 45.134312, 2.65, 2.65, 2.64, 2.55, 2.52, 2.5, 
    2.74, 3.5, 2.96, 4.44, 4.62, 4.3, 3.98, 3.81, 4.78, 4.43, 
    3.97, 3.87, 3.91, 3.72, 3.74, 4.3, 4.08, 4.1, 4.37, 4.08, 
    4.15, 4.59, 4.05, 3.97, 3.77, 3.79, 3.66, 3.57, 3.39, 3.41, 
    3.32, 3.27, 3.29, 3.5, 3.45, 3.4, 2.9, 3.05, 3.09, 3.22, 
    3.35, 3.45, 5.39, 3.93, 3.78, 3.59, 3.62, 4.4, 3.82, 3.63, 
    3.21, 3.18, 3.26, 3.01, 252.5, 253, 255, 265.5, 280, 287.5, 
    287, 295, 291.5, 291.5, 286, 285, 285, 282, 288.5, 291.5, 
    292.5, 294, 291.5, 291, 285, 287.5, 291, 290, 290, 295, 290.5, 
    292.5, 295, 291.5, 309.5, 311, 307.5, 315, 317.5, 316.5, 
    311.5, 319.5, 318.5, 316.5, 319.5, 326.5, 328, 338, 332.5, 
    358, 386, 382, 373, 377, 368.5, 368, 375, 379.5), Low = c(126.760002, 
    128.429993, 126.379997, 127.860001, 130.229996, 128.5, 126.860001, 
    128.490005, 128.759995, 127, 126.940002, 128.550003, 133.589996, 
    135.020004, 136.539993, 141.369995, 140.410004, 136.699997, 
    130.210007, 130.929993, 134.610001, 133.610001, 134.589996, 
    135.860001, 134.919998, 135.850006, 134.399994, 133.770004, 
    133.690002, 132.789993, 129.470001, 127.410004, 128.800003, 
    125.599998, 118.389999, 122.230003, 120.540001, 121.199997, 
    122.790001, 125.010002, 121.839996, 118.620003, 117.57, 116.209999, 
    118.790001, 119.449997, 121.260002, 119.160004, 120.419998, 
    124.720001, 122.339996, 120.32, 119.68, 120.260002, 122.139999, 
    120.07, 119, 118.919998, 120.730003, 118.860001, 23.85, 24.08, 
    24.620001, 25.059999, 25.389999, 25.34, 25.75, 25.700001, 
    25.559999, 24.99, 24.99, 25.049999, 24.98, 24.969999, 24.41, 
    24.389999, 24.16, 24.85, 24.07, 24.1, 24.67, 24.77, 25.110001, 
    25.950001, 26.309999, 27.09, 26.940001, 26.93, 27.23, 27, 
    26.23, 25.959999, 26.65, 26.799999, 26.49, 27.209999, 27.219999, 
    28.83, 29.16, 29.33, 29.52, 27.85, 28.120001, 29.559999, 
    29.85, 30.01, 29.969999, 30.120001, 30.08, 30.389999, 30.26, 
    30.219999, 29.68, 29.860001, 29.440001, 29.360001, 28.969999, 
    30.02, 31.01, 30.959999, 7.18, 7.33, 7.42, 7.3, 7.52, 7.28, 
    7.51, 8.83, 8.41, 8.6, 8.63, 9.13, 8.91, 9, 9.11, 9.33, 9.6, 
    9.35, 9.37, 8.94, 9.04, 9.7, 9.62, 9.41, 9.59, 9.57, 9.67, 
    9.99, 10, 10.14, 10.14, 10.68, 10.28, 10.04, 9.9, 9.76, 10.04, 
    9.72, 9.88, 10.24, 10.22, 9.94, 9.3, 9.67, 9.44, 9.7, 9.86, 
    9.69, 9.08, 8.8, 8.65, 9, 9.02, 9.17, 9.47, 9.57, 9.3, 9.65, 
    9.87, 10.02, 36.335529, 36.239231, 36.953876, 37.774963, 
    38.393311, 38.332489, 38.307144, 35.570198, 36.117588, 36.933605, 
    37.658386, 37.97263, 38.469337, 38.028381, 37.257984, 37.987835, 
    37.10593, 36.938671, 36.680183, 36.847439, 38.732895, 38.90015, 
    39.559048, 40.136848, 40.293968, 39.939178, 39.746578, 39.45768, 
    39.96452, 39.771919, 39.84288, 39.619869, 40.567661, 40.314243, 
    39.042068, 40.755196, 40.025341, 40.54739, 41.09478, 41.63203, 
    41.83477, 41.277245, 42.255447, 43.051189, 43.588444, 43.968575, 
    44.602131, 44.429802, 44.713634, 44.73391, 44.668018, 44.627472, 
    44.37405, 44.059807, 42.985302, 43.507347, 43.030918, 43.694881, 
    44.485554, 44.404461, 2.47, 2.49, 2.45, 2.47, 2.44, 2.4, 
    2.44, 2.55, 2.7, 2.73, 3.33, 3.61, 3.61, 3.39, 4.05, 3.91, 
    3.6, 3.57, 3.61, 3.45, 3.46, 3.69, 3.86, 3.89, 3.91, 3.7, 
    3.82, 3.9, 3.75, 3.67, 3.58, 3.46, 3.48, 3.29, 2.9, 3.14, 
    3.1, 3, 3.11, 3.16, 3.16, 2.75, 2.5, 2.8, 2.81, 2.97, 3.16, 
    3.17, 4, 3.47, 3.48, 3.32, 3.35, 3.71, 3.46, 3.1, 3.02, 2.88, 
    2.92, 2.83, 250, 250.5, 250, 252.5, 264.5, 279, 280, 283, 
    284.5, 283.5, 279, 282, 275, 277.5, 280, 282, 284, 287, 285.5, 
    284, 280.5, 283.5, 285, 287, 287, 289, 287, 288.5, 290, 288.5, 
    291, 301, 299, 307, 306, 309, 307, 312, 309, 312, 314.5, 
    316.5, 319, 329, 322, 355, 360, 368, 365, 365, 362, 363.5, 
    364, 374), Close = c(129.410004, 131.009995, 126.599998, 
    130.919998, 132.050003, 128.979996, 128.800003, 130.889999, 
    128.910004, 127.139999, 127.830002, 132.029999, 136.869995, 
    139.070007, 142.919998, 143.160004, 142.059998, 137.089996, 
    131.960007, 134.139999, 134.990005, 133.940002, 137.389999, 
    136.759995, 136.910004, 136.009995, 135.389999, 135.130005, 
    135.369995, 133.190002, 130.839996, 129.710007, 129.869995, 
    126, 125.860001, 125.349998, 120.989998, 121.260002, 127.790001, 
    125.120003, 122.059998, 120.129997, 121.419998, 116.360001, 
    121.089996, 119.980003, 121.959999, 121.029999, 123.989998, 
    125.57, 124.760002, 120.529999, 119.989998, 123.389999, 122.540001, 
    120.089996, 120.589996, 121.209999, 121.389999, 119.900002, 
    24.110001, 24.459999, 24.959999, 25.75, 25.530001, 25.780001, 
    25.91, 25.709999, 25.620001, 25.17, 25.139999, 25.200001, 
    25.360001, 25.27, 25.02, 24.620001, 24.85, 24.870001, 24.34, 
    24.48, 24.889999, 25.23, 25.950001, 26.15, 27.299999, 27.09, 
    27.15, 27.379999, 27.49, 27.16, 26.280001, 26.41, 27.1, 27.120001, 
    27.379999, 27.969999, 28.190001, 28.969999, 29.58, 30.040001, 
    29.82, 28.07, 29.75, 30.16, 30.1, 30.26, 30.34, 30.280001, 
    30.790001, 30.43, 30.74, 30.309999, 30.08, 30.469999, 29.58, 
    29.370001, 29.889999, 31.66, 31.07, 31.559999, 7.62, 7.63, 
    7.48, 7.56, 7.91, 7.39, 8.05, 8.83, 8.82, 8.8, 9.18, 9.31, 
    9.05, 9.22, 9.27, 9.75, 9.9, 9.79, 9.44, 9.13, 9.68, 9.71, 
    10.16, 9.84, 9.86, 9.75, 10.18, 10.06, 10, 10.3, 10.66, 10.68, 
    10.72, 10.04, 10.18, 10.04, 10.26, 9.81, 10.28, 10.3, 10.42, 
    9.96, 9.98, 9.77, 9.64, 9.97, 10.34, 9.81, 9.12, 9.08, 8.91, 
    9.28, 9.27, 9.45, 9.7, 9.72, 9.67, 10.04, 10.04, 11.28, 36.741005, 
    37.232639, 37.541813, 38.692348, 39.138367, 38.332489, 38.90015, 
    36.102383, 37.126205, 37.638115, 37.942219, 39.052204, 38.976177, 
    38.489609, 38.35783, 38.540295, 37.435379, 37.46579, 36.943741, 
    37.480991, 39.113026, 39.406994, 40.19767, 40.34972, 40.516979, 
    40.339584, 40.334515, 40.293968, 40.572731, 40.263557, 40.172325, 
    40.39027, 40.937656, 40.937656, 40.831223, 41.403954, 40.385201, 
    41.08971, 42.113533, 41.920933, 42.372021, 41.966549, 43.258995, 
    43.137356, 43.836796, 44.439938, 44.91637, 45.017738, 45.261024, 
    45.149517, 46.264572, 44.657883, 44.414597, 44.272682, 43.461735, 
    43.765839, 43.583378, 45.103905, 44.708565, 44.901165, 2.54, 
    2.56, 2.48, 2.53, 2.49, 2.47, 2.58, 2.88, 2.86, 3.85, 4.33, 
    3.86, 3.72, 3.67, 4.39, 3.95, 3.68, 3.79, 3.65, 3.64, 3.73, 
    3.89, 4.06, 3.99, 3.99, 3.87, 4.09, 3.99, 3.84, 3.81, 3.74, 
    3.5, 3.58, 3.32, 3.16, 3.35, 3.17, 3.15, 3.25, 3.19, 3.38, 
    2.85, 2.87, 2.83, 3.04, 3.13, 3.25, 3.41, 4.2, 3.6, 3.53, 
    3.44, 3.46, 3.9, 3.48, 3.19, 3.14, 2.98, 3.02, 2.98, 251, 
    253, 254, 261.5, 279.5, 283.5, 281, 288.5, 288, 287, 283, 
    285, 276, 282, 284.5, 290, 284, 293, 288.5, 286.5, 283.5, 
    285.5, 288.5, 287, 288.5, 289.5, 289, 290, 290, 290.5, 300.5, 
    305.5, 304, 307.5, 316.5, 313.5, 311, 315.5, 313, 312.5, 
    317.5, 323.5, 326, 331, 325.5, 358, 377.5, 368.5, 365.5, 
    366, 365, 365, 374, 377), Volume = c(143301900, 97664900, 
    155088000, 109578200, 105158200, 100384500, 91951100, 88636800, 
    90221800, 111598500, 90757300, 104319500, 120150900, 114459400, 
    157611700, 98390600, 140843800, 142621100, 177523800, 106239800, 
    83305400, 89880900, 84183100, 75693800, 71297200, 76774200, 
    73046600, 64280000, 60145100, 80576300, 97918500, 96856700, 
    87668800, 103916400, 158273000, 111039900, 148199500, 164560400, 
    116307900, 102260900, 112966300, 178155000, 153766600, 154376600, 
    129525800, 111943300, 103026500, 88105100, 92403800, 115227900, 
    111932600, 121229700, 185549500, 111912300, 95467100, 88530500, 
    98844700, 94071200, 80819200, 85671900, 8041600, 7856500, 
    8471800, 9288400, 7514100, 8907000, 7280700, 6596600, 8290500, 
    8364600, 6794200, 6270500, 7160000, 6684500, 9953100, 11548300, 
    12948600, 9292900, 14666900, 9353000, 5952800, 6300500, 6963400, 
    7267500, 8426300, 7065500, 6267500, 6265600, 3941200, 6380700, 
    9402800, 7345300, 8979600, 9524800, 11845500, 8275900, 18366000, 
    26078200, 17327800, 10928600, 10059700, 14448400, 13688900, 
    13142600, 10337000, 11820400, 10122500, 9478300, 12813700, 
    10605200, 12590100, 11022700, 49810500, 14955000, 10313100, 
    9073900, 9561200, 13195700, 9661500, 7219500, 83611650, 54929799, 
    74271331, 84604245, 86075192, 102371633, 79414541, 197884127, 
    109982524, 80422292, 91118563, 96550807, 94292124, 94477124, 
    81654255, 73542509, 97691196, 85212478, 102037047, 152757640, 
    89270360, 79700143, 185967050, 151264162, 95283438, 93966987, 
    73408512, 112247074, 0, 48745087, 91993205, 107716602, 85765697, 
    94476970, 88294485, 116854253, 60498562, 131866599, 59830565, 
    56868864, 40605892, 68620795, 81049108, 100672551, 98591427, 
    80373221, 84194484, 179149010, 120183953, 69550997, 146016633, 
    132973809, 115768221, 68422263, 98604636, 75576844, 111896231, 
    90423078, 87564925, 185333431, 6927203, 4051555, 5155844, 
    4542635, 5304213, 2937402, 2739511, 15098974, 8655156, 6529052, 
    4898170, 6958771, 4772095, 2249417, 2686437, 2520508, 5637650, 
    5227858, 3720683, 3231379, 8058324, 2721754, 2943321, 3535616, 
    9876049, 8452332, 9603578, 3077091, 3497340, 6170952, 3593819, 
    3027174, 3269853, 5745968, 5043975, 3969676, 5594047, 6943776, 
    4621753, 2937205, 5848564, 5422791, 6930557, 6884981, 4318897, 
    4408866, 7447286, 2858088, 5621472, 5880329, 6162468, 6201731, 
    7791772, 6212385, 5250745, 5446269, 3417039, 5169063, 4094567, 
    4601036, 126200, 183800, 166900, 123100, 196500, 174800, 
    1763100, 5231200, 720300, 19880400, 4989400, 1400500, 659500, 
    591300, 2667100, 974400, 492600, 430200, 359800, 472700, 
    330700, 446000, 253100, 224400, 958700, 410000, 428000, 1170000, 
    359200, 436500, 197600, 220000, 104100, 160500, 339200, 133000, 
    127200, 123900, 148900, 183200, 191800, 450900, 211200, 178600, 
    166700, 108400, 172300, 1365000, 21941400, 1773600, 652700, 
    640700, 438000, 7759900, 790000, 493900, 443800, 374900, 
    457800, 271000, 1531749, 1951835, 2984653, 7274739, 11062445, 
    6315052, 5002981, 6375090, 4895819, 4334120, 3271007, 2671114, 
    4781170, 3610802, 4410983, 5231348, 3685064, 6288355, 3658600, 
    3775896, 2111191, 3387713, 3497993, 2036209, 1343523, 5191787, 
    3506596, 2980292, 4613852, 3589534, 9921364, 5578897, 6592137, 
    7414500, 5360155, 4942528, 3721495, 3875339, 3400830, 3114473, 
    4899739, 6153285, 3263518, 4816497, 4860266, 15912474, 24595161, 
    10145606, 4882067, 5020497, 3602197, 3851223, 4463345, 4093079
    ), Adjusted = c(128.087051, 129.670715, 125.305794, 129.581619, 
    130.700089, 127.661453, 127.483322, 129.551926, 127.592194, 
    125.840279, 126.523224, 130.680298, 135.470795, 137.648331, 
    141.458984, 141.696518, 140.607758, 135.688568, 130.611023, 
    132.768723, 133.610031, 132.57077, 135.985504, 135.564209, 
    135.712906, 134.820755, 134.206177, 133.948471, 134.18634, 
    132.025421, 129.695953, 128.575867, 128.734451, 124.898293, 
    124.759514, 124.253975, 119.932098, 120.19973, 126.672638, 
    124.025993, 120.992737, 119.079613, 120.358337, 115.342583, 
    120.031212, 118.930923, 120.893608, 119.971748, 122.905869, 
    124.472054, 123.669128, 119.47612, 118.940826, 122.311119, 
    121.468552, 119.039955, 119.535583, 120.150177, 120.32859, 
    118.851631, 22.97263, 23.30612, 23.78253, 24.535265, 24.325645, 
    24.563852, 24.687717, 24.497149, 24.4114, 23.982626, 23.954041, 
    24.011209, 24.163662, 24.077909, 23.839703, 23.458572, 23.677723, 
    23.696781, 23.19178, 23.325174, 23.715836, 24.039793, 24.725832, 
    24.916397, 26.012144, 25.812054, 25.869221, 26.088369, 26.193184, 
    25.878748, 25.040262, 25.164127, 25.821581, 25.840637, 26.088369, 
    26.650537, 26.860161, 27.603363, 28.184587, 28.622889, 28.413265, 
    26.745821, 28.346567, 28.737228, 28.865732, 29.019173, 29.095894, 
    29.038353, 29.527437, 29.182199, 29.479488, 29.06712, 28.84655, 
    29.22056, 28.367054, 28.165665, 28.664345, 30.361763, 29.795958, 
    30.265865, 7.023958, 7.033176, 6.894909, 6.968651, 7.291274, 
    6.811949, 7.420323, 8.13931, 8.130093, 8.111658, 8.461934, 
    8.581765, 8.342102, 8.498805, 8.544894, 8.987349, 9.125615, 
    9.024219, 8.701595, 8.415845, 8.922823, 8.950477, 9.365276, 
    9.070309, 9.088743, 8.987349, 9.383713, 9.2731, 9.217793, 
    9.494327, 9.826166, 9.844603, 9.881474, 9.254663, 9.383713, 
    9.254663, 9.457456, 9.042655, 9.475891, 9.494327, 9.60494, 
    9.180922, 9.199357, 9.005784, 8.885953, 9.19014, 9.531199, 
    9.042655, 8.406627, 8.369755, 8.213053, 8.554111, 8.544894, 
    8.710814, 8.941258, 8.959695, 8.913606, 9.254663, 9.254663, 
    10.397669, 36.204769, 36.689232, 36.993893, 38.127636, 38.567142, 
    37.773026, 38.332405, 35.57547, 36.584351, 37.088787, 37.388454, 
    38.482239, 38.407318, 37.927856, 37.797997, 37.977798, 36.889011, 
    36.91898, 36.404549, 36.933956, 38.542171, 38.831852, 39.610985, 
    39.760818, 39.925636, 39.750828, 39.745831, 39.705875, 39.980572, 
    39.675911, 39.58601, 39.800777, 40.340172, 40.340172, 40.235294, 
    40.799664, 39.79578, 40.490005, 41.498886, 41.309097, 41.753601, 
    41.354046, 42.627632, 42.507767, 43.196999, 43.791336, 44.260815, 
    44.360703, 44.600441, 44.490559, 45.58934, 44.006104, 43.766365, 
    43.626522, 42.827412, 43.127075, 42.947277, 44.445614, 44.056042, 
    44.245834, 2.54, 2.56, 2.48, 2.53, 2.49, 2.47, 2.58, 2.88, 
    2.86, 3.85, 4.33, 3.86, 3.72, 3.67, 4.39, 3.95, 3.68, 3.79, 
    3.65, 3.64, 3.73, 3.89, 4.06, 3.99, 3.99, 3.87, 4.09, 3.99, 
    3.84, 3.81, 3.74, 3.5, 3.58, 3.32, 3.16, 3.35, 3.17, 3.15, 
    3.25, 3.19, 3.38, 2.85, 2.87, 2.83, 3.04, 3.13, 3.25, 3.41, 
    4.2, 3.6, 3.53, 3.44, 3.46, 3.9, 3.48, 3.19, 3.14, 2.98, 
    3.02, 2.98, 201.808319, 203.416351, 204.220367, 210.250504, 
    224.722809, 227.938889, 225.928833, 231.958969, 231.556946, 
    230.752945, 227.536865, 229.144897, 221.908752, 226.732849, 
    228.742889, 233.164993, 228.340881, 235.577042, 231.958969, 
    230.350922, 227.938889, 229.546906, 231.958969, 230.752945, 
    231.958969, 232.76297, 232.360962, 233.164993, 233.164993, 
    233.567001, 241.607147, 245.627258, 244.421219, 247.235306, 
    254.471436, 252.059402, 250.049362, 253.667419, 251.657379, 
    251.255371, 255.275467, 260.099548, 262.109589, 266.1297, 
    261.707581, 287.838135, 303.51651, 296.280334, 293.868286, 
    294.270294, 293.466278, 293.466278, 300.702423, 303.114471
    )), row.names = c(NA, -354L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

The pipe that I am trying to make into a function:

```
timeseries_wide <- timeseries %>%
  as_tibble%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(names_col), values_from = all_of(values_col),
              names_glue = "{names_col}.{.value}")
```

A typical call:

```
values_col = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
names_col = "Key"


timeseries_wide <- timeseries %>%
  as_tibble%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(names_col), values_from = all_of(values_col),
              names_glue = "{names_col}.{.value}")
```

The current function I have return an error about "names_col" not being unique (or absent).

```
pivot_prices_wider <- function(data, nameS, valueS){


    data <- data %>%
      tibble::as_tibble(.)%>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(nameS), 
                         values_from = all_of(valueS),
                         names_glue = "{{nameS}}.{.value}"
                         )
    

}
```

In some instances, names_col will contain several columns, values_col can contain 1 or more columns. I will expand this function to handle uniting two "name" columns, and work on the sister function for long pivots.

I want the final columns names as **"AAPL.Open"** which is not the default, thus need to use the glue_name argument.
However, I get an error when calling this pipe inside the function:

```
Error in `check_pivot_spec()`:
! The `.name` column of `spec` must be unique.
Backtrace:
 1. prices_ts %>% as_tibble %>% ...
 5. tidyr:::pivot_wider.data.frame(...)
 6. tidyr::pivot_wider_spec(...)
 7. tidyr::check_pivot_spec(spec)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the evaluation. I tried:

```
  vars_nameS <- rlang::enquo(nameS)

...

names_glue = "{!!vars_nameS}.{.value}"
```

I am following [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#tidy-selection) and the `tidyeval` cheatsheet but getting a bit confused about whether I should use the embrace operator {{ }} or `rlang`.

P.S. **Any recommended resources on learning how to debug a pipe/function containing pipes?**

---

It seems that using glue directly works for this particular example:

```
pivot_prices_wider2 <- function(data, nameS, valueS){

    data <- data %>%
      tibble::as_tibble(.data)%>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(nameS), 
                         values_from = all_of(valueS),
                         names_glue = glue::glue("{[nameS]}.{.value}", .open="[", .close = "]")
                         )
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just needing

```r
library(tidyverse)

pivot_prices_wider <- function(data, nameS, valueS){
  
  data %>%
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(nameS), 
                       values_from = all_of(valueS),
                       names_glue = "{.name}") %>%
    rename_with(~sapply(strsplit(.x, "_"), 
                        function(x) paste0(x[2:1], collapse = ".")))
}
```

Allowing

```r
values_col = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
names_col = "Key"

timeseries %>% 
  pivot_prices_wider(names_col, values_col)
#> # A tibble: 61 x 37
#>    NA.Date    AAPL.Open HPQ.Open 0992.~1 DELL.~2 ACER.~3 2357.~4 AAPL.~5 HPQ.H~6
#>    <date>         <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2021-01-04      134.     24.7    7.18    37.5    2.64    250.    134.    24.9
#>  2 2021-01-05      129.     24.1    7.48    36.4    2.54    251     132.    24.7
#>  3 2021-01-06      128.     24.6    7.5     37.2    2.57    254     131.    25.4
#>  4 2021-01-07      128.     25.3    7.46    38.0    2.5     255     132.    25.8
#>  5 2021-01-08      132.     25.7    7.56    38.8    2.51    265     133.    25.9
#>  6 2021-01-11      129.     25.5    7.78    38.7    2.48    282.    130.    25.9
#>  7 2021-01-12      128.     25.8    7.51    38.4    2.49    285     130.    26.2
#>  8 2021-01-13      129.     26.0    9.25    37.9    2.63    285     131.    26.0
#>  9 2021-01-14      131.     25.6    8.75    36.1    2.85    290.    131     25.9
#> 10 2021-01-15      129.     25.5    8.65    37.1    3.01    289     130.    25.6
#> # ... with 51 more rows, 28 more variables: `0992.HK.High` <dbl>,
#> #   DELL.High <dbl>, ACER.High <dbl>, `2357.TW.High` <dbl>, AAPL.Low <dbl>,
#> #   HPQ.Low <dbl>, `0992.HK.Low` <dbl>, DELL.Low <dbl>, ACER.Low <dbl>,
#> #   `2357.TW.Low` <dbl>, AAPL.Close <dbl>, HPQ.Close <dbl>,
#> #   `0992.HK.Close` <dbl>, DELL.Close <dbl>, ACER.Close <dbl>,
#> #   `2357.TW.Close` <dbl>, AAPL.Volume <dbl>, HPQ.Volume <dbl>,
#> #   `0992.HK.Volume` <dbl>, DELL.Volume <dbl>, ACER.Volume <dbl>, ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I could get where you are, and tidyverse was loaded.
The issue is with the column names. You are showing the default "Value_Name".

I am trying to get to "Name.Value" using the names_glue argument of pivot.

Comment: @PierreO this is a simple fix using `rename_with` - see my update

Comment: That a solution for sure :) thanks
Anyway you could explain why the embracing operator did not work there?

Comment: `names_glue` seems only to look for column names, ignoring external variables, since it works off `glue::glue_data` internally, which is passed the current data frame as the search environment.